# How to count the number of a digit in a sequence of squares

Tags: c

There is a sequence of squares: 149162536 (1 4 9 16 25 36 ...)
How do I get a digit that has a n-number? Example:n = 5, answer 6. n = 2, answer 4. n = 9, answer 6.

Comment: How long is the sequence of squares? How many digits do you have to read from it? Can it use extra memory on the stack/heap to store the sequence or do the square numbers have to be recalculated every time? Without more specifics the answer might as well be `int n = 5; printf("n = %d, answer %c", n, "149162536"[n-1]);`.

Comment: The sequence of squares can be very long. We do not know. We just need to get one digit. We input sequence number and want to get a digit that stands under this sequence number. n can be 1000 or 10000 or more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution seems rather easy with a brute force approach:

1. start with `i = 0`.
2. compute `i*i` and convert to a string with `snprintf`. Let `len` be the length of this string.
3. if `n >= len` increment `i`, subtract `len` from `n` and continue at step 2.
4. otherwise, return the character of the string at offset `n`.

Here is some code:

```c
int find_char_in_square_sequence(unsigned long long n) {
    for (unsigned long long i = 0;; i++) {
        char buf[32];
        unsigned int len = snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "%llu", i * i);
        if (n < len)
            return buf[n] - '0';
        n -= len;
    }
}
```

For large index values, a more efficient approach would handle ranges of values with squares of the same size in a single step, reducing the time complexity from **O(N log N)** to just above **O(log N)**.

Comment: Thx so much. Do you happen to know how to write [unsigned int len = snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "%llu", i * i)] in C #?

Comment: No I don't, but I suppose you can convert a number to a string with a cast?